# how do i format microtime code

Tags: php, optimization, microtime

I'm having trouble with this php code. not really great at coding.

```
function time() {
return round(microtime(true) * 1000);
}
```

this dosent work due to php not reading it correctly, and my host wont change precision in php.ini i read somewhere there's little sense in using microtime with true as parameter, went messing with code had it working just fine until i messed it up again.

this is my code now, it dosent seem to work anymore.
need it sec msec without space and dot epoch Example: "13856484375004820824"

```
function time() {
round(microtime(true) * 1000); 
return ini_set('precision', 20);
round(str_replace('.', '', microtime(1)));//string(20) "13856484375004820824" 
}
```

any ideas how to fix it, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Its easy when you know how, this should solve the problem without the use of str_replace

```
function time()
{
return intval(microtime(true) * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `return` on `ini_set()` you need to return string which contains data you want.
Also you propably get error because `time()` is already declared so might consider using `my_time()` or something like that.

```
function my_time() {
   ini_set('precision', 20);
   return round(str_replace('.', '', microtime(1)));//string(20) "13856484375004820824" 
}
```